# Issue mapping dataframe Numpy types to Python types

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need some way to map dataframe types to python-ish types (a slightly custom mapping). Right now i'm doing this:

```
def get_p_type(n_type):
    if numpy_type in [numpy.float16, numpy.float32, numpy.float64]:
        return "float"
    elif numpy_type in [numpy.datetime64]:
        return "datetime"
    else:
        return "string"

def main():
    data_frame = pandas.DataFrame({"foo":datetime.datetime.now()}, index=[0])
    for column in data_frame.columns:
        print(get_p_type(data_frame[column].dtype))
```

This works for floats, but doesn't work for datetime. I set some debug print statements, and I see that the n_type from the above code is actually 'datetime64[ns]', so i'm getting a string. I don't see any numpy types that match to anything like that.

Is there some better way to do this? If not, is there some way to fix the above datetime issue?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try `np.issubdtype(df['A'].dtype, np.datetime64)`. issubdtype in general looks like a better way to do this.

Comment: Yes! That worked perfect. Thanks!